I don't know what's meaning of {.}^
When I installed and configured open-rmf and rmf-web, I found the below definitions in package.json:
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start": "concurrently npm:start:rmf-server npm:start:react",
  "start:rmf-server": "RMF_SERVER_USE_SIM_TIME=true npm --prefix ../api-server start",
  "start:react": "pnpm run --filter {.}^... build && react-scripts start",
  ...
}

What does that --filter {.}^... expression mean?

https://pnpm.io/filtering?

pnpm run --filter {.}^... build means run the build script in all the dependencies of the project in the root of the workspace, except of the root project itself. Only those dependencies are picked that are inside the workspace (not those in node_modules)
